# Running git commands from ruby script

Tags: ruby, git

Kind of a stupid question, but I'm not able to run git commands from a ruby script. Do I need to be sourcing something?

Simple example of script:

```
   checkout = %x("/usr/bin/git version")
puts checkout
```

Output:

```
sh: /usr/bin/git version: No such file or directory
```

If I run the command from the cmd line it works:

```
git version 1.7.9.5
```

Any input appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use `which git` to figure out where your `git` actually resides.

Comment: This is a bit late, but the reason for the error is the quotes inside your `%x`, had you done `%x(/usr/bin/git version)` instead then you would have gotten the git version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or [Kernel#exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) or this quotes ``:

```
  $> irb
  => `git status`
  => "# On branch develop\nnothing to commit, working directory clean\n"
  => system('git version')
  => git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
  => exec('git version')
  => git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
```

in script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts system('git version')
puts `git version`
puts exec('git version')
```

output:

```
git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
true
git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
```

Comment: Nah, I need to run git commands on arguments I pass to a script. irb won't work for me here...

Comment: @user797963 IRB is just being used as an example, anything you write in IRB can be copy-pasted into a Ruby script and run from there. It's identical.

Comment: Be warned that `exec` will not return. If you plan to do anything with the results of your git call, you need to use a different method like `system` or the backticks.